# (HTML) How to line up text fields?

Tags: html, css

I have a form.

Here is what it currently looks like: 
[image: Sample]

And here is how I want it to look:
[image: Sample 2]

How would I line up the fields like in the second screenshot? Also, if anyone has any other tips to make it look nicer (like making the drop down boxes the same size) that would be awesome.

```html
<body>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="JAILdead" value="dead"> Jailor:
    <input type="text" name="TIname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="TIdead" value="dead"> Town Investigative:
    <select name="TI">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="sheriff">Sheriff</option>
      <option value="invest">Investigator</option>
      <option value="spy">Spy</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="TIname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="TPdead" value="dead"> Town Protective:
    <select name="TP">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="bg">Bodyguard</option>
      <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="TPname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="TKdead" value="dead"> Town Killing:
    <select name="TK">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="vet">Veteran</option>
      <option value="vig">Vigilante</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="TKname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="TSdead" value="dead"> Town Support:
    <select name="TS">
      <option value=" "></option>
      <option value="mayor">Mayor</option>
      <option value="mayor">Medium</option>
      <option value="ret">Retributionist</option>
      <option value="trans">Transporter</option>
      <option value="escort">Escort</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="TSname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="RTdead" value="dead"> Random Town:
    <select name="RT">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="sheriff">Sheriff</option>
      <option value="invest">Investigator</option>
      <option value="spy">Spy</option>
      <option value="bg">Bodyguard</option>
      <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
      <option value="vet">Veteran</option>
      <option value="vig">Vigilante</option>
      <option value="mayor">Mayor</option>
      <option value="mayor">Medium</option>
      <option value="ret">Retributionist</option>
      <option value="trans">Transporter</option>
      <option value="escort">Escort</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="RTname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="RTdead" value="dead"> Random Town:
    <select name="RT">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="sheriff">Sheriff</option>
      <option value="invest">Investigator</option>
      <option value="spy">Spy</option>
      <option value="bg">Bodyguard</option>
      <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
      <option value="vet">Veteran</option>
      <option value="vig">Vigilante</option>
      <option value="mayor">Mayor</option>
      <option value="mayor">Medium</option>
      <option value="ret">Retributionist</option>
      <option value="trans">Transporter</option>
      <option value="escort">Escort</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="RTname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="RTdead" value="dead"> Random Town:
    <select name="RT">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="sheriff">Sheriff</option>
      <option value="invest">Investigator</option>
      <option value="spy">Spy</option>
      <option value="bg">Bodyguard</option>
      <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
      <option value="vet">Veteran</option>
      <option value="vig">Vigilante</option>
      <option value="mayor">Mayor</option>
      <option value="mayor">Medium</option>
      <option value="ret">Retributionist</option>
      <option value="trans">Transporter</option>
      <option value="escort">Escort</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="RTname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="RTdead" value="dead"> Random Town:
    <select name="RT">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="sheriff">Sheriff</option>
      <option value="invest">Investigator</option>
      <option value="spy">Spy</option>
      <option value="bg">Bodyguard</option>
      <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
      <option value="vet">Veteran</option>
      <option value="vig">Vigilante</option>
      <option value="mayor">Mayor</option>
      <option value="mayor">Medium</option>
      <option value="ret">Retributionist</option>
      <option value="trans">Transporter</option>
      <option value="escort">Escort</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="RTname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="GFdead" value="dead"> Godfather:
    <input type="text" name="GFname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="MAFdead" value="dead"> Mafioso:
    <input type="text" name="MAFname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="RMdead" value="dead"> Random Mafia:
    <select name="RM">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="framer">Framer</option>
      <option value="bmer">Blackmailer</option>
      <option value="consort">Consort</option>
      <option value="consig">Consigliere</option>
      <option value="janitor">Janitor</option>
      <option value="disg">Disguiser</option>
      <option value="forger">Forger</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="RMname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="RMdead" value="dead"> Random Mafia:
    <select name="RM">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="framer">Framer</option>
      <option value="bmer">Blackmailer</option>
      <option value="consort">Consort</option>
      <option value="consig">Consigliere</option>
      <option value="janitor">Janitor</option>
      <option value="disg">Disguiser</option>
      <option value="forger">Forger</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="RMname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="NEdead" value="dead"> Neutral Evil:
    <select name="NE">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="exe">Executioner</option>
      <option value="witch">Witch</option>
      <option value="jester">Jester</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="NEname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="NKdead" value="dead"> Neutral Killing:
    <select name="NK">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="sk">Serial Killer</option>
      <option value="ww">Werewolf</option>
      <option value="arso">Arsonist</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="NKname">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 1:
    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 2:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 3:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 4:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 5:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 6:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 7:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 8:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 9 :

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 10:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 11:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 12:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 13:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 14:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="guydead" value="dead"> 15:

    <input type="text" name="guynotes">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: im not sure if you are bot or something but if someone could let me know which code is relevant i will post that seperately but im not really sure

Comment: I meant that you shouldn't include external links, but rather that you should include the code directly in the question itself. However, I've edited the question to do that for you =]

Comment: okay thank you, sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 1):

For each line of your form, you can wrap the first `input` and `select` with a `div`, and give that `div` a width to make your second `input` line up correctly.

```css
.form-portion-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 260px; /*modify this value to fit your form*/
}

.form-portion-1 select {
  float: right;
  width: 100px; /*modify this value to fit your form*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-portion-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="JAILdead" value="dead"> Jailor:
    </div>

    <input type="text" name="TIname">
    <br>
    <div class="form-portion-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="TIdead" value="dead"> Town Investigative:
      <select name="TI">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="sheriff">Sheriff</option>
      <option value="invest">Investigator</option>
      <option value="spy">Spy</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="TIname">
    <br>
    <div class="form-portion-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="TPdead" value="dead"> Town Protective:
      <select name="TP">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="bg">Bodyguard</option>
      <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="TPname">
    <br>
    <div class="form-portion-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="TKdead" value="dead"> Town Killing:
      <select name="TK">
      <option value=" "> </option>
      <option value="vet">Veteran</option>
      <option value="vig">Vigilante</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="TKname">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you very much. the CSS part of HTML is really going over my head I need to figure this stuff out!

Comment: @dyl4n130 no problem, let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need twitter bootstrap and the bootstrap grid system it will solve all of your problems :) A non bootstrap solution would be to put your data in tables with padding or create inline-block divs and consistent widths.